# Number of comparisons and swaps of the heap sorting method

Tags: c, sorting, heapsort

We have implemented in C the heapsort sorting algorithm to sort the data of a structure.. I need to display the number of comparisons that have been made and the number of interchanges, in order to compare the practical and theoretical complexity.

To count iterations and interchanges, I have 2 variables that I increment.
The question is, if I increment them where appropriate, because the result is the same. ?
I guess something's missing because, in my case, for a number of 90000 records, I get comparisons: 1312958 and swaps: 1312958.

I have here a trivial implementation of the heap sort method

```
void heapify(Game *game, int n, int i, size_t *compCounter, size_t *swapCounter) {
    int largest = i;
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;
    if (left < n && game[left].id > game[largest].id) {
        largest = left;
    }
    if (right < n && game[right].id > game[largest].id) {
        largest = right;
    }
    if (largest != i) {
        (*compCounter)++;
        (*swapCounter)++;
        swap(&game[i], &game[largest]);
        heapify(game, n, largest, compCounter, swapCounter);
    }
}

Game *heapSort(Game *game, int n, size_t *compCounter, size_t *swapCounter) {
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        heapify(game, n, i, compCounter, swapCounter);
    }
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        swap(&game[0], &game[i]);
        heapify(game, i, 0, compCounter, swapCounter);
    }
    return game;
}
```

UPDATE

I changed the place where the variables are counted, obtaining the following results: 2895916 comparisons and no swaps: 1402958. Considering that heap sort has the theoretical complexity N * LogN, 2895916 far exceeds the number 90000 * log (90000)

```
void heapify(Game *game, size_t n, size_t i, size_t *compCounter, size_t *swapCounter) {
    int largest = i;
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;
    if (left < n && game[left].id > game[largest].id) {
        largest = left;
    }
    *compCounter += 1;
    if (right < n && game[right].id > game[largest].id) {
        largest = right;
    }
    *compCounter += 1;
    if (largest != i) {
        swap(&game[i], &game[largest]);
        *swapCounter += 1;
        heapify(game, n, largest, compCounter, swapCounter);
    }
}

Game *heapSort(Game *game, size_t n, size_t *compCounter, size_t *swapCounter) {
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        heapify(game, n, i, compCounter, swapCounter);
    }
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        swap(&game[0], &game[i]);
        *swapCounter += 1;
        heapify(game, i, 0, compCounter, swapCounter);
    }
    return game;
}
```

```
int main(){

size_t heapComp = 0, heapSwap = 0;
 heapSort(games5, n, &heapComp, &heapSwap);
   
    printf("Comps: %zu si nr swaps: %zu\n", heapComp, heapSwap);
}
```

Comment: you increment both variables the same place so how should they ever differ?

Comment: `swap(&game[0], &game[i]);` isn't counted as a swap. Why not?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Okay, I'm doing this because that's where I thought those variables should be incremented. I did not state that it was right what I did, that's why I wrote here ))

Comment: `game[left].id > game[largest].id` isn't counted as a compare. Why not?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Daca contorizez acet pas, obtin un numar de comparatii ce nu se incadreaza in complexitatea O(N*log(N)). Credeam că nu este ok.

Comment: To count swaps, increment `*swapCounter` when you do a swap. To count comparisons, increment `*compCounter` when you do a comparison.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If I count this step, I get a number of comparisons that do not fit into the complexity of O(N*log(N)). I thought it wasn't OK.

Comment: @Anderson, you must increment the comparison counter once every time an element comparison is performed, regardless of the result, and not otherwise.  You must update the swap counter every time a swap is performed.  It's not clear to me why you think the code presented implements that.  FWIW, it would probably be easiest and clearest to put the counter increments as close as possible to the actual comparisons and swaps they are meant to count.  I recommend also being consistent about whether you increment your counters before or after the operations being counted.

Comment: Maybe this is a matter of understanding the O notation. Roughly, a function T(n) being O(f(n)) means that there exists a constant, c, such that T(n) <= c*f(n) no matter how big n is. The constant can be very big, it just cannot depend on n. Hence saying that an algorithm uses O(n) comparisons does not limit the number of comparisons for a fixed n. It could be 5000 comparisons for n=5.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok, how can I calculate the theoretical complexity of this algorithm in this case?

Comment: @Anderson, your revised code looks fine to me, except that it is not clear whether `*compCounter` and `*swapCounter` are initialized.  Probably these should both be set to zero at the beginning of function `heapSort()`.  There could also be issues around how that function is called, so if things still don't seem right to you then it would help to show an example of how a call is set up and performed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the call I make in the main function, variables here also initialize them with 0, n is the number of elements read in the file. `size_t heapComp = 0, heapSwap = 0; heapSort(games5, n, &heapComp, &heapSwap);`

Comment: In addition to @nielsen's comments, note well although ratios of logarithms are independent of the base of the logarithm, individual logarithms of the same argument depend greatly on the base.  If you want to compare the stats you collect on a single run of your sort to the formula *N*log*N*, then, given that you're using a binary heap, the most appropriate base for the logarithm would be 2.  And 90000 * log2(90000) is about 1481187, which is very much in line with the stats you observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are not counting the comparisons properly: you must separate the tests to identify when the comparisons actually occur.

Here is a modified version:

```
void heapify(Game *game, int n, int i, size_t *compCounter, size_t *swapCounter) {
    int largest = i;
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;
    if (left < n) {
        (*compCounter)++;
        if (game[left].id > game[largest].id) {
            largest = left;
        }
    }
    if (right < n) {
        (*compCounter)++;
        if (game[right].id > game[largest].id) {
            largest = right;
        }
    }
    if (largest != i) {
        (*swapCounter)++;
        swap(&game[i], &game[largest]);
        heapify(game, n, largest, compCounter, swapCounter);
    }
}
```